# How to pass "Before you continue to Google Search" with Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Good evening,

Consider the following code:

```py
# openSearchResults.py - Opens several search results.

import bs4
import pyinputplus as pyip
import requests
import webbrowser

inp = pyip.inputStr(prompt="What are you looking for? ")
print('Searching...')
res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(inp))
res.raise_for_status()
print(f"Status: {res.status_code}")


# Retrieve top search result links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)  # output the css and html (temporarly for debugging)
# Open a browser tab for each result.
linkElems = soup.select('.package-snippet')

numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems)) # numOpen = 0 here, therefore the for loop does not execute
for i in range(numOpen):
    urlToOpen = 'https://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href')
    print('Opening', urlToOpen)
    webbrowser.open(urlToOpen)
```

**What is it:** This program attempts to solve the task from Al Sweigart's book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python"

**What does it do:** The program intends to take input from the user, perform a google search and automatically open several tabs with a couple of the first results.

**Problem:** Printing the `soup` variable shows that the program runs into `Before you continue to Google Search` window [(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdmrC.jpg).

**What I tried so far:** I've attempted to use `driver.find_element(By.ID, "L2AGLb").click()` from `selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` as suggested [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), however, I've got `Unresolved reference 'driver'` error. PyCharm automatically solves the issue by importing `from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver`, which replaces the error with a warning `Cannot find reference 'find_element' in 'driver.pyi'`.

What else can I try to bypass the `Before you continue to Google Search` window?

Comment: Is it still a non-solved question? Or did you handle it?

Comment: Sadly I didn't figure out a way to solve it

Comment: this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68532019/can-i-accept-or-ignore-the-google-privacy-notice-when-webscraping-with-beautiful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer I was looking for:

```
# res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(inp)) wrong approach
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
cookies = {"CONSENT": "YES+cb.20210720-07-p0.en+FX+410"}
res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(inp), headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Adding the User-Agent header and CONSENT cookie did the job.